# dropdown not working when i click on the child elements

Tags: javascript, html

hi my code is not working as i expected when i click on the child elements the dropdown changes to display: none

I have an error when I click on the input frame and display : none how can I fix it

I want to click on the `nav__panel-user class`, it will show the dropdown, and the second click will hide it, and clicking outside the dropdown will also be hidden.

my code

```js
function openLogin() {
  const navUserDropdown = document.querySelector(".navUser__dropdown-user");
  if (navUserDropdown.style.display === "block") {
    navUserDropdown.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    navUserDropdown.style.display = "block";
  }
}
window.onclick = function (event) {
  if (!event.target.closest(".nav__panel-user")) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("navUser__dropdown-user");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.style.display === "block") {
        openDropdown.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<div class="nav__panel-user" onclick="openLogin()">
    <div class="nav__block-user">
        <a class="nav__user-bottom">
            <i class="fa-regular fa-user" style="font-size: 20px; "></i>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="navUser__dropdown-user">
        <div class="dropdown__user-account">
            <form class="dropdown__user-account--form">
                <div class="user__account-form--title">
                    Đăng nhập
                </div>
                <div class="user__account-form--group">
                    <input type="text" class="account__form-user--input" placeholder="Tài khoản" />
                </div>
                <div class="user__account-form--group">
                    <input type="text" class="account__form-user--input" placeholder="Mật khẩu" />
                </div>
                <div class="user__account-form--group_btn">
                    <button class="account-menu__form-button">
                        Đăng nhập
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.navUser__dropdown-user {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 559px;
  background: var(--white);
  color: #3d464d;
  width: 280px;
  right: 15px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: Which one is your Dropdown? You js Code hides your .navUser__dropdown-user Elements

Comment: .navUser__dropdown-user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using a toggle function with the link element if you don't want it to be disabled then you need to add toggle attribute with `acctive`

css

```
active {
display: block;
}
```

js

```
function openLogin() {
  const navUserDropdown = document.querySelector(".navUser__dropdown-user");

  if (!navUserDropdown.contains(event.target)) {
    navUserDropdown.classList.toggle("active");
  }
}

window.onclick = function (event) {
  if (!event.target.closest(".nav__panel-user")) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("navUser__dropdown-user");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains("active")) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove("active");
      }
    }
  }
};
```